# ¿Es ofensivo para los creyentes mencionar "hostia" como interjección?

Tags: españa, vulgaridades, interjecciones, religión

Según la RAE [*hostia*](http://dle.rae.es/hostia) tiene una connotación religiosa:

> 1. f. Hoja redonda y delgada de pan ácimo, que se consagra en la misa y con la que se comulga.

**Pregunta:** ¿Es ofensivo mencionar, especialmente frente a los creyentes (normales, no radicales), la palabra *hostia* en alguno de sus significados calificados por RAE como "malsonantes"? (los cuales son la mayoría, de hecho)

> 3. f. vulg. malson. Golpe, trastazo, bofetada.
>      mala ~.
> 4. f. vulg. malson. Mala intención.
>      a toda ~.
> 5. loc. adv. vulg. malson. A toda velocidad.
>      de la ~.
> 6. loc. adj. vulg. malson. Muy grande o extraordinario. Se ha comprado un coche de la hostia.
>      hostia, u hostias.
> 7. interjs. vulgs. Denotan sorpresa, asombro, admiración, etc.
>      la ~.
> 8. loc. adv. vulg. malson. la leche.
>      ser alguien o algo la ~.
> 9. loc. verb. vulg. Ser extraordinario.

Comment: Bueno, no es que sea según el DRAE, es que realmente es algo religioso, se dice así y el diccionario solo lo recoge como tal :P

Comment: @JoulSauron Sí, eso es muy cierto. Sólo pretendía mostar una actitud neutral.

Comment: Parece que esos otros significados son mas bien en España, pues nunca los he escuchado en Colombia.

Answer (score 5):

No es ofensivo desde el punto de vista de los creyentes, es otro de los significados de la palabra, sin más. Aún así, sí es una palabra malsonante y puede resultar "ofensiva" en contextos formales.

Answer (score 2):

El habla española está plagada de palabras o expresiones de origen religioso que se usan coloquialmente: "¡la virgen!", hostia, copón, "¡virgen santa!", o incluso "¡me cago en Dios!". Aunque pueda sonar fuerte, generalmente no se interpretan como blasfemia, ya que se interpetan como interjecciones y no con el significado literal. Decía Antonio Machado que un pueblo que no blasfema es porque no cree en Dios.

Eso sí, en lenguaje formal estas expresiones no encajan mucho.

Nota de localización: esta respuesta habla de mi experiencia como nativo español. En distintas partes del mundo se habla el español de forma diferente, y es posible que estas expresiones suenen peor.

Answer (score 0):

No es que sea o no ofensiva para los creyentes. Es que, fuera de su contexto, se trata de una blasfemia (concierne al segundo Mandamiento: "no tomarás el nombre de Dios en vano") y las blasfemias, en cuanto tal, a quien ofenden es a Dios.
Otra cosa es que se usen habitualmente, incluso por los católicos; o que a los que queremos al Señor nos duelan; pero blasfemia claro que es, no porque lo diga yo, sino porque lo dice el Catecismo.