# ¿Uso de "joder" en la serie "Los Serrano"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, significado

En la serie "Los Serrano" (de España) los personajes usan la palabra *joder*. El [Traductor de google](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/joder) lo traduce como *fuck*. El [Diccionario de RAE](http://dle.rae.es/joder) tiene muchas acepciones y no puedo entender si esta palabra es ofensiva o no. Dudo que esta palabra pueda usarse en ese serie, quizás yo oí mal. Entonces, qué dicen?

Comment: Curiosamente en Chile "joder" es informal pero no ofensivo, y no tiene significado sexual. Significa a veces "molestar" (_Déjate de joder!_) y a veces "dañar" (_Ando jodido de la espalda_, _se jodió el motor_).

Comment: Joder significa todo lo que tu quieras en español. Se puede utilizar para expresar desagrado, admiración, sorpresa, fastidio, dolor... A pesar de ello, no deberías incorporarla a tu vocabulario.

Comment: Por cierto, me he tomado la libertad de editar tu pregunta para hacerla más "española".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende del contexto, puede tener precisamente este significado sobre todo en España.

Pero que conste que no es una palabra tan fuerte como *fuck* en inglés. Para mí, tiene una intensidad algo más fuerte que *damn*.

En otros contextos, por ejemplo en *mi coche está jodido*, significa más bien *messed up* o *non-functioning*; en tales casos, una traducción como *fucked (up)* normalmente de debe considerar errónea

Comment: Gracias por el respuesta. ¿Pero cual es la palabra que corresponde a *fuck*?

Comment: @user2277240 dependerá del contexto. No hay una correlación perfecta entre las palabrotas entre idiomas. En inglés, esas palabras tienen potencias diferentes según país y región y contexto (por ejemplo *shit* como interjección, valor literal como excremento, o valor figurativo como de poco valor; estos tres usos tiene niveles diferentes de ofensa). Como lo mismo pasa en español, para una buena traducción de palabrotas, tendrías que definir el dialecto/registro de entrada (del inglés) y salida (del español), más el contexto.

Comment: Como dice @guifa, depende en el contexto. Joder tambien puede decir "to bother" o molestar en Ingles.

Answer (score 2):

> "Dudo que esta palabra pueda usarse en ese serie"

Date cuenta que la "intensidad" de la palabrota es un factor cultural ([como explica guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12369/5481)). Desde luego, es ofensiva y malsonante, y a evitar si no quieres ser tachado de usar un lenguaje soez.

Las series y películas en España la usan como reflejo del lenguaje cotidiano. Lo mismo ocurriría con películas o series americanas con palabras como "fuck" o "asshole". La diferencia es que probablemente en el cine puedas escuchar esas palabras sin censurar en los diálogos y en la televisión oirás un ¡¡beep!! cuando los protagonistas la pronuncian. En España por lo menos no hay censura de esas palabras, aunque existen franjas horarias en las que no puedes emitir cierto tipo de contenidos. Esa es una razón por la que puedes oír ese tipo de vocabulario en series españolas.

El factor cultural hace que esas palabras malsonantes sean tolerables en la televisión (probablemente mientras la serie o película con ese contenido no esté en horario infantil). No en vano en español se oyen a veces [interjecciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4798/5481) que podrían resultar realmente ofensivas para ciertos colectivos, y que serían impensables en otras culturas.

Comment: La serie es para toda la familia incluyendo los niños, por eso me inclino a considerar la respuesta de guifa de ser mas correcta. Ademas en la serie esta palabra dicen tanto adultos como los niños y nadie hace ninguna notificacion a nadie. Significa algo mas cerca a *damn* que a *fuck*.

Comment: La respuesta de guifa es correcta (ya estaba marcada como respuesta aceptada cuando posteé mi ampliación), pero tienes que considerar el contexto y el factor cultural. No discuto la traducción al inglés de "joder". Mientras que en España puede ser común oír un "me cago en Dios" (mira el enlace), en EEUU hay quien usa un "jeez" o "Oh, my gosh" para evitar "Jesús!" o "Oh, Dios mío". Estás en lo correcto al sospechar que **no** es una palabra adecuada en una serie "para toda la familia". Que no te engañe el tipo de serie. **"Joder" no es más suave por ser usada en la televisión**.

Comment: Sobre el uso del lenguaje, "Los Serrano" será para toda la familia (con los estándares de _Telecinco_, eso sí), pero entre [las frases míticas de un solo personaje](http://www.infoseriestv.com/15130/recordando-las-mejores-perlas-de-fiti-en-los-serrano/) encontramos: "gilipollas", "maricón", "ostias", "coñito",  (¿Es _"puta"_ lo de “Está que se rompe la hija de ****”?) y por supuesto "joder" y sus derivadas, como "jodío". A destacar los valores familiares con: "Joder Raul! Tu eres un maricón de libro" y “Cuando le pillé a Raúl su revistita guarra a sus 8 años, uno se queda ya más tranquilo…”