# What is the word which sounds like "shtrass"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

A friend of mine who is from Barcelona often uses a word, which sounds like "shtrass" (I suppose it might be spelled *estrás*, but it don't find anything related on Google except a type of a stone). He uses it to express things like "incredible", "wow", "Oh my God", so a sort of an exclamation. Which word might it be?

Comment: Do you ever ask your friend to write down a word he just said?  (By carrying a bit of paper and a stub of pencil in your pocket?)

Comment: @aparente001 indeed I use an notes app for this, but I didn't want to ask for this specific word for some reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the word you are looking for is

## ostras

Which translates as oysters.

As indicated by the official language:

> [**ostras**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RJkChD7)
>   `Eufem. por hostias`.
>
> 1. interj. coloq. U. para expresar disgusto, asombro, etc.
>
> > [**hostia**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Ki2xstc)
> >     `Del lat. hostia 'víctima de un sacrificio'`.
> >
> > *hostia, u hostias*
> >     1. interjs. malsons. Denotan sorpresa, asombro, admiración, etc.

That is, *ostras* is an interjection to show annoyance, surprise and many other things. The funny thing is that it is used instead of *hostias* (communion bread), which is an interjection marked by the dictionary as rude ('malsonante').

See related questions for more information:

- [¿Es ofensivo para los creyentes mencionar "hostia" como interjección?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4786/1674)
- [Minced oaths in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29047/1674)

Comment: That's great.  I thought OP was going for the German Strasse!